# cypress tests to check date format ( angular)

Tags: angular, cypress

I'm  working on cypress testing an angular project, I need help with one of my tests. I am trying to write a tests to verify date format  ('dd/MM/yyy').
So, with that i need to verify the date format not its value. There is a way on Cypress  to verify that?

Thanks.

```js
dd/mm/yyyy => yyyy-mm-dd
   formatDate(date: string): string {
      return date.toString().split('/').reverse().join('-');
   }

   get calculateResidentAge(): number {
      const date = new Date(
         this.formatDate(this.screeningReportData.resident.dob),
      );
      const ageDifMs = Date.now() - date.getTime();
      const ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
      return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
   }
}
```

```html
    <p class="resident-details__meta-text">
                           <span class="muted">DoB</span>
                           {{
                              screeningReportData.resident.dob
                                 | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
                           }}
                           <!--Output age of user -->
                           <span class="muted"
                              >({{ calculateResidentAge }} years old)</span
                           >
                        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think your confusing the purpose of a cypress test - cypress tests for integration of software.

Assuming this is front-end Angular code - at the level you're looking at it's fine to assume date is of the format required. Comment your `formatDate` code to say so. Better yet name it `formatDate(dateAsDayMonthYearString: string)`.

`date.toString()` is suspect code when the signature is `formatDate(date: string)`

If you need to create a date to send to the backend that's a UI issue.

Incoming data from server/database should have been validated there.

If you don't trust the data source, or it may coming in both UK vs US format for example, verify it on arrival and transform it.